# How does Dropbox upload data to its servers?

Tags: upload, amazon-s3, client, dropbox

just recently I was thinking and wondered, how does Dropbox upload my files to its S3 storage and how might that one be organized?

Let's just completely forget about the sync aspect for a second and scale the problem down to one S3 bucket.

Say, in that bucket's root directory you have lots of folders, each belonging to an arbitrary user.

Now if that user wants to upload a file to his folder... how does that happen internally? I mean, Dropbox can't just store the Amazon S3 access credentials/keys hard-coded into the application (be it on ios or windows) as it might get reverse-engineered and thus exposed.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is old and might not get a reply. But just wanted to know. Does dropbox store directly to S3 or stores the info about the files in database of its backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way websites don't allow users to directly access their databases but rather provide interfaces that can control permissions and handle authentication, I'm sure Dropbox has some kind of application that the client on your computer interacts with.  Their server daemon will have permissions to write to the disk, but your computer has to go through it (and it's security procedures) before anything your computer sends is written.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I were to develop an application that makes use of Dropbox's REST API and uploads an image to the user's folder what'd happen is: 1. I make the POST call to the Dropbox REST API. 2. If my supplied credentials are correct, 3. The Dropbox server accepts my 2megabytes of image-data... 4.and "redirects" the request by making another POST request to Amazons S3 REST API supplying the exact same 2 megabytes of image data,...again?

Comment: I don't know if I'm just overthinking this but it seems to me like an incredible bottleneck to have the API first receive a huge chunk of data, have it written to it's own storage/memory only to then forward that data to Amazon. That's why I came up with the question above. Can't you just upload that data directly to Amazon S3 in some way?

Comment: There's nothing to say that their web services are not running on the same boxes that the data is saved to.  Once the authentication is performed, the web programs could just pipe the data from their buffers straight to disk.  Any kind of extra layer is always going to add some kind of performance hit, but security is almost always an extra layer :).  After just glancing through the API docs, it looks like they use OAuth, so yes, is it a web service handling the request.

Comment: Just because it is using the HTTP protocol though does not mean that it's running something that would be inefficient for this.  For example, I highly doubt that they're running an Apache/PHP combo for their REST API.  They likely have something either custom or modified so that it can authenticate and then pump data through as quickly as both connection speeds will allow with minimal superfluous buffering.

Comment: I thank you for clarifying this :-) Very much appreciated. - I don't know I guess I was just hoping for some magic trick that solves this problem without crapping all over the performance :D

Comment: Really with a properly tuned server (or more likely a custom written server) the performance wouldn't be hit too badly by the various protocol overheads.  But anyway, glad to be of help :).

Answer (score 2):

Some guys from EADS did reengineering on Dropbox, the presentation slides are available for download: [A CRITICAL ANALYSIS OF
DROPBOX SOFTWARE SECURITY](http://archive.hack.lu/2012/Dropbox%20security.pdf)